# How to add custom behaviour to browser back button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using external data visualization service and I have connected it's content with routes. So, for example '/scorecard' will display Scorecard raport, that is contained within data visualization service's object.

I use React with react-router-dom.

The trick is, I do not change my React component based on these routes, as I do not want to re-instantiate data visualization each time user changes page. So, what is changed are route itself and I call the API for report change (check below code for example)

I tried window.onbeforeunload event without success, as I do not change the page. I do not want to replace expected back button behaviour, but add additional API call to revert to previous report.

```
onButtonClick = (dashboardName) => {
    if (this.props.currentViz) { //check if external API object is instantiated
        this.props.history.push(dashboardName);     

        this.props.currentViz
            .getWorkbook()
            .activateSheetAsync(dashboardName);
    };
};
```

Currently, I am changing report with success on navigation, but when I press native browser back button, only route is changed. I expect my data visualization to go to previous report.

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: What kind of Router do you use? It should be possible to simply call a function instead of replacing the component. Just treat the url as a variable and send the value to the current component.

Comment: Hey, I use react-router-dom

Comment: You can use url parameters to treat the url as a variable for the current component: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params